# how can I find peaks position

Tags: differential-equations

[image]

Please help me how can I get the peaks position automatically?

Comment: Look at documentation for  [`FindPeaks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html)

Answer (score 5):

Note that `FindPeaks` as suggested by @BobHanlon is a step in the right direction! But there's still some work to be done, as it does not accept lists of coordinate pairs, which it looks like you have.

So, you'll need to `SortBy` the first element, get the second, `FindPeaks`, and then replace the x-results with the appropriate values from the original data...one way to do this is

```
findpeaks2D[data_, s_:0, args___] :=
   {data[[Floor[#1],1]], #2} & @@@ FindPeaks[Last/@SortBy[data, First], s, args]
```

Then we have, for example,

```
data = Table[{x + RandomReal[{-0.05, 0.05}], Sin[x]}, {x, 1, 10, 0.1}];

ListPlot[{data, findpeaks2D[data]}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, PointSize[0.025]}]
```

[image: a ListPlot of a slightly noisy discretely-sampled sine wave with the peaks highlighted in orange.]

(To verify that we have actually obtained points in the original data, note that `ContainsAll[data, findpeaks2D[data]]` evaluates to `True`.)

This by default avoids gaussian blurring; see the docs for `FindPeaks` for how to use the optional arguments to this function, which are fed directly to `FindPeaks`.